# Count number of times value appears in particular column in a DataTable with linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am importing data into a dataTable. I want to retrieve certain data using linq instead of sql.

1) Count number of times value appears in particular column getting the highest value

2) Get the total records in one column.

Below is what I would have done in SQl

```
select count(*) as c FROM OrderDetails GROUP BY productID ORDER BY c     DESC LIMIT 1
select count(productID) FROM OrderDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cnt1 = OrderDetails
    .GroupBy(od => od.ProductID)
    .Select(od => od.Count())
    .OrderByDescending(od => od)
    .Take(1);

var cnt2 = OrderDetails.Count();
```